# Variance of stock returns in Schwert (1989)

Tags: variance, finance

[Schwert (1989)](http://schwert.ssb.rochester.edu/jfin89a.pdf) writes on page 1117:
"The estimator of the variance of the monthly return is the sum of the squared daily returns (after subtracting the average daily return in the month): $$\hat \sigma_t^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} r^2_{it}$$
where there are $N_t$ daily returns $r_{it}$ in the month $t$.
"

Why doesn't he divide $\sum_{i=1}^{N_t} r^2_{it}$ by the number of days in the month $t$, $N_t$? That is, why isn't he calculating the variance of the returns as in: $$\hat \sigma_t^2 = \frac{1}{N_t} \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} r^2_{it} \quad ?$$

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64172/variance-of-annual-return-based-on-variance-of-monthly-return